Singularity showed cleanup error and says some directories do not exist
I tried to submit a job via PBS queue system, here is my script:
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N cp2k
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -q noor2
#PBS -m e
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=64

export SPACK_ROOT=/home/s22117712r/software/spack
source ${SPACK_ROOT}/share/spack/setup-env.sh

spack load gcc@11.4.0 mpich@4.0.3

ulimit -s unlimited
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4


cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

SINGPATH=/home/s22117712r/software/apptainer-cp2k-2023.2/cp2k2023-apollo.sif
apptainer exec -B ${PWD}:/mnt -H /mnt ${SINGPATH} mpirun -np 64 cp2k.psmp cp2k.inp | tee ${2:-out.log}

Then error occured:
INFO:    Cleanup error: while unmounting /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/final directory: no such file or directory, while unmounting /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/rootfs directory: no such file or directory
FATAL:   container creation failed: open /etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory

I just checked my sandbox, it showed I have these directories:
[s22117712r@apollo session]$ pwd
/home/s22117712r/software/apptainer-cp2k-2023.2/cp2k2023/var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session
[s22117712r@apollo session]$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 s22117712r users 10 Apr  7 17:37 final
drwxr-xr-x 2 s22117712r users 10 Apr  7 17:37 rootfs

How should I revise my script or sandbox?

In apptainer command, instead of ${PWD} you may try ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}
This variable will specifically points to the directory where qsub is issued
